# UpdateAnimationExtender Property Key - What properties are available to me?

Tags: asp.net, animation, updatepanel, properties

I have the following generic .net code to change the background colour of a label. Lovely.

```
<asp:UpdatePanelAnimationExtender ID="UpdatePanel1_UpdatePanelAnimationExtender" 
            runat="server" Enabled="True" TargetControlID="UpdatePanel1">
        <Animations>
        <OnUpdating>
        <Color
        AnimationTarget="lblSearchResults1"
            Duration="1"
            StartValue="#FF0000"
            EndValue="#666666"
            Property="style"
            PropertyKey="backgroundColor"/>
```

However, how do I go about finding the available other property keys available to me?

Are these just the generic style options available to most .net controls?

For example, how do I change the fore color?

As always, apologies for asking simple questions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yup - found it - generic html styles.

Apologies.